# Frequency array dynamic allocation using C

Tags: c

I have a function that goes through my array of strings to find out how many times that string occurs with in an array. If found, the string will be set to `NULL` and a counter keeps track of how many times the string is found. I then call another function within the loop to allocate memory for my frequency array so that I can store `count`. It seems to work fine, but when I go and create any other variable within main my program crashes. Here are my two functions:

```
int search(char **table, int **frequency, int wordSize)
{
//  Local Declaration
int i, j, k;
int count = 1;
int strCount = 0;
char target[25];

// Statement
for(i = 0, k = 0; i < wordSize; i++)
{
    if(table[i] != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(target, table[i]);
        for(j = i + 1; j < wordSize; j++)
        {
            if(table[j] != NULL &&
               strcmp(target, table[j]) == 0 &&
               target != table[i])
            {
                count++;
                free(table[j]);
                table[j] = NULL;
            }
        }
    strCount += makeFreq(frequency, k, count);
    k++;
    }
    count = 1;
}

return strCount;
}// search


int makeFreq(int **frequency, int k, int count)
{
//  Local Declaration
int strCount = 0;

//  Statement
frequency[k]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
frequency[k][0] = count;
strCount += 1;

return strCount;
}// makeFreq
```

Can someone explain to my why my program is crashing?

Here I allocated 1000 pointers for my table.

```
char** getPoint(void)
{
//  Local Declaration
char **table;

//  Statement
table = (char**)calloc(MAX_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
if(table == NULL)
{
    MEM_ERROR, exit(100);
}

return table;
}// getPoint
```

Than I read I allocate memory for the strings in my file and store it into the array of strings.

```
int scanFile(char **table, FILE *fpFile)
{
//  Local Declaration
int count = 0;
char temp[500];
char **ptr = table;

//  Statement

//  scan file, allocate, and copy string to array.
while(fscanf(fpFile, "%s", temp) != EOF)
{
    *(ptr + count) =(char*)calloc(strlen(temp)+1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*(ptr + count), temp);
    count++;
}

return count;
}// scanFile
```

Here is how I allocated the array of pointers for my frequency array.

```
void aloFreqAry(int **frequency, int wordSize)
{
//  Local Declaration

//  Statement
frequency =(int**)calloc(wordSize + 1, sizeof(int));
if(frequency == NULL)
{
    MEM_ERROR, exit(103);
}

return;
}// aloFreqAry
```

Comment: Can you show how you're allocating the memory for table and frequency in your main() function ? It might have something to do with that.

Comment: @Tuxdude - okay give me a second to upload it.

Comment: And, always compile with the highest warning level.

Comment: @Tuxdude - okay I uploaded the functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I'm using codeblocks right now and I'm not sure how to turn on all the warnings, because when I use visual studio to check for memory leaks, I know it shows way more warnings that codeblocks didn't catch.

Comment: `frequency[k]=(int*)malloc` - [AAAAARGH!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @H2CO3 If you don't want a heart attack before you're 22, you really need to develop some indolence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Indeed. (Well, I have more serious problems than malloc, that really hurt, this is just annoying.)

Comment: @Nathan Don't know codeblocks, but there ought to be something like "Project settings" where you can put compiler flags. `-Wall -Wextra` is a decent warning level for gcc and clang.

Comment: As a small improvement in readability, you can replace the `calloc()`/`strcpy()` combo in `scanFile()` with `table[count] = strdup(temp);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the problem of the sizes in the allocations (should be `sizeof(char*)` in the allocation of `table`, and `sizeof(int*)` in the allocation of `frequency`),

```
void aloFreqAry(int **frequency, int wordSize)
{
//  Local Declaration

//  Statement
frequency =(int**)calloc(wordSize + 1, sizeof(int));
if(frequency == NULL)
{
    MEM_ERROR, exit(103);
}

return;
}// aloFreqAry
```

doesn't allocate anything to the `frequency` in the caller. It just allocates memory to the local copy of that pointer, and loses the handle to that when the function returns.

Instead of taking an `int**` as argument, the function should return one,

```
frequency = calloc(wordSize + 1, sizeof(int*)); // size of a _pointer_ to int
if(frequency == NULL)
{
    MEM_ERROR, exit(103);
}

return frequency;
```

that you assign in the caller.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It makes perfect sense now. I really appreciate your time and effort for helping me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This statement looks suspect (where you say "Here I allocated 1000 pointers for my table"):

```
table = (char**)calloc(MAX_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
```

That doesn't look like an allocation of pointers, but an allocation of a char buffer.

Perhaps you mean:

```
table = (char**)calloc(MAX_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: The same problem with `int` in the allocation of `frequency`.